# Storing embedded entity in Datastore, it's ignoring exclude_from_indexes from embedded

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, gcloud-python, google-cloud-python

I'm trying to have a embedded entity with a field that is larger than 1500bytes. Based on the documentation, it's recommended to exclude that field from Indexes, and it should allow 1MB.

I add that field to the exclude_from_indexes key of the embedded entity. When I try and save the parent Entity it tells me the field is bigger than 1500bytes. If I save the embedded entity independently, it works.

Is exclude_from_indexes ignored on embedded entity?

```
client = datastore.Client(dataset_id=projectID)
record_key = client.key('Record', my_id)
record_entity = datastore.Entity(record_key)

embedded_key = client.key('Data', another_id)
embedded_entity = datastore.Entity(key=embedded_key,exclude_from_indexes=('big_field',))
embedded_entity['field1']='1234'
embedded_entity['big_field']='large string bigger than 1500bytes'

record_entity['RandomFieldName']=embedded_entity

client.put(record_entity)
#Error: gcloud.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 The value of property &quot;big_field&quot; is longer than 1500 bytes.

client.put(embedded_entity)
#No Error
```

Comment: Embedded Entities are tricky! Ancestor keys might be a much better way to do this, but there are trade-offs. This might be a bug in the library or not supported by Datastore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a valid call. You can try it out yourself by using the [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/datastore/datastore/v1beta2/datastore.datasets.commit) for Datastore.

It's likely a bug inside `gcloud-python` which doesn't properly pass along the indexing information when you use an embedded entity.

I see you also filed a [bug on the `gcloud-python` github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-python/issues/1206), I would recommend following along there.

Comment: Thanks, will continue the conversation via Github.

Comment: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/5111#issuecomment-553331578 This is the answer - in case someone wants to jump straight to the github